# BST Binary Tree Remove function in C the leaves with value = 0

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a function in C that should be able to remove (delete) all the leaves from a binary tree (BST), which is passed as a parameter, with zero value (0) and the return result will be the number of the deleted leaves. NOTE: Not the nodes with value = 0 but ONLY the leaves. For example to the  BST on the figure:

[image]

the function will return 2 (after removing the red circled zeros).

Comment: Yes but it is totally wrong. I missed something from the theory of the BST. So if it is possible to give me the way how this will be created, it will be great!

Comment: I am tempted to supply a working solution, but as there is no proof that OP has written any code himself, I'm out of here.

Comment: Excuse me @Weather Vale but as I mentioned before I am totally unaware how to create it. It will be fault from my side to put a code that it is Nothing.

Comment: I agree with you @Vitor Lima but I suppose that I was trying into the session thread to explain my problem in a short and a detailed way.

Comment: Just to throw out a line, consider the right-hand side of the tree diagram above, `0 -> 0 -> 0`. After deleting the leaf with 0 data, that *leaves* (geddit?) its father as a 0 value leaf node. Should that be deleted too?

Comment: It should be but no. For the above attached example... the result should be 2... this is for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pseudo code to do it:

```
int delete_zero_leaves (node){
    int deleted
    delete_zero_leaves_aux (node, &deleted);
    return deleted
}

pointer delete_zero_leaves_aux (node, deleted){
    boolean is_leaf = true
    // if there is a child
    if (node->left != NULL){
            // passing deleted by reference
            node->left = delete_zero_leaves_aux (node->left, &deleted)
            is_leaf = false
    }
    // if there is a child on the right side
    if (node->right != NULL){
            // passing deleted by reference
            node->right = delete_zero_leaves_aux (node->right, &deleted)
            is_leaf = false
    }
    if (is_leaf AND node->value == 0){
        free(node)
        deleted += 1
        return NULL
    }
    return node
}
```

Since you said the *node* has no pointer the its own father, you can return a pointer and set the value of the father's pointer (left or right).

Comment: It depends on the representation of your tree. Normally, you should just call *free* and adjust some pointers. In this case, as the deleted node is always a leaf, you just need to set the pointer from its father to it as NULL.

Comment: So the father needs to be informed to delete the left or right node.

Comment: And how will the father be informed?

Comment: How about returning a negative number if the node is to be deleted? It has to be deleted by the father and not by the leaf, so the left/right pointer can also be set to `NULL` (unless you also pass a **node pointer?)

Comment: @WeatherVane could you please give an example for our reference?

Comment: I edited the code... But, as I said, it depends on the way you represent your tree.

Comment: @Marcellus has amended the answer.

Comment: @Marcellus The tree has only reference to left and right nodes. Nothing else. and let's say it `code` int deleteZeroLeaves(tree * t)

Comment: Edited now. You can pass deleted by reference (the first value is supposed to be zero).

Comment: @Marcellus please note that deleteZeroLeaves (tree *t) has only one parameter... the binary tree.

Comment: Ok, so, just make `deleteZeroLeaves(tree *t) { int deleted = 0;  delete_zero_nodes(t, &deleted); return deleted; }`

Comment: @Marcellus you still have same calls to `code` delete_zero_nodes into `code` delete_zero_nodes with one parameter. e.t.c. `code` delete_zero_nodes (node->right)